# How to access modem's web gui from inside LAN?

Tags: router, routing, modem

When my Netgear CG3000 is in bridge mode it acts as a modem-only, but it still exposes valuable information about the Internet connection through its web gui.

However I cannot seem to access the modem's web gui from inside the LAN.

Here's a drawing of the setup:

```
 LAN            <-->   Router           <-->   Modem             <--->  ISP
 (192.168.1.x)         (192.168.1.1)           (192.168.1.100)
                       Zyxel NBG4615v2         Netgear CG3000
```

Actually I had expected that I could access 192.168.100.1 from inside the LAN without further ado. Can't.

The router has facilities for setting Static Routes. What route should I set exactly?

I've tried setting the following static route in the Zyxel router:

```
Destination: 192.168.100.0
Gateway: 192.168.100.1
Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: All I see is three networking devices.  Which device is your computer connected to?

Comment: It's on the LAN. (left-hand side of drawing)

Comment: You actually describe 2 indivual LAN networks.  Trying to make sure I understand the configuration.  So LAN is the actual device on the 192.168.1.x network

Comment: My LAN network (where all client computers are connected) is 192.168.1.x. Now, supposedly the modem exposes a web gui on address 192.168.100.1, which - as you can tell - is distinct from the LAN subnet. Accessing a modem GUI which sits behind a router seems to be a common problem. I can find many posts on the issue but none that have made me any wiser.

Comment: Did you perhaps make a typo in your modem’s IP address above? What’s your router set to do? DHCP? What does it say about its WAN IP address?